# Double Not operator

Tags: javascript, boolean, negation

I saw this line of code in a book:

```
!!(document.all && document.uniqueID);
```

Why is it necessary to use the double not operator? Do not the `&&` operator already transform the result to a Boolean?

Comment: IMO !! is unnecessary here

Comment: No, the && operator doesn't change the result to a boolean, and yes, it may be necessary, depending on whether you need or not a boolean.

Comment: @lombausch Why do you say that ? If the author wants a boolean, this may be necessary.

Comment: " *However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value* " : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: @AlexK. :) I had no idea it works like this. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` will return the value of `document.uniqueID` (if `document.all` has any value other than '',`false, null, undefined, 0, NaN`) for `document.all && document.uniqueID`:

```
 for Example 45 === (true && 45) //true
```

From [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Logical AND (&&) expr1 && expr2 returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, it returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, it returns false.

So it is necessary to use `!!` to convert the above expression into `Boolean`.